# Do I need to escape get_the_post_thumbnail function?

Tags: theme-development, security

I am developing a WordPress theme for WordPress.org. Do I need to escape `get_the_post_thumbnail` function? I want to use it outside the loop. So, I won't be able to use `the_post_thumbnail`. Please let me know if I need to escape `get_the_post_thumbnail` and if yes, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to escape the data. And it doesn't need to be escaped. Please take a look at [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L42) function, it didn't do any escaping. So no worries.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, the functions start with get_ generally [return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) data while non-prefixed counterparts [echo](http://www.php.net/echo) (i.e. print) data.

`the_post_thumbnail()` works only in the post code (loop) and return featured an image of the current post.

`get_the_post_thumbnail()` works everywhere and get $post_id parameter at first attribute.

For eaxample:

```
the_post_thumbnail($params) = get_the_post_thumbnail($current_post_id,$params);
```

This is realization in WP engine:

```
function the_post_thumbnail ($size='post-thumbnail', $attr=''){
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size, $attr );
}

function get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id = null ) {
    $post_id = ( null === $post_id ) ? get_the_ID() : $post_id;
    return get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true );
}
```

if `$post_id` is NULL - used `get_the_ID()` of current post.

I think you don't need to escape `get_the_post_thumbnail` function.

Comment: Hey @nilesh, please this